# Directional buffer zone in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, buffer

From the city point I want to create multiple buffer zone for 8 directions. For example I am attaching an image. What is the procedure to do that in QGIS or any suitable method like Google Earth Engine.

[image]

Comment: You really need to add more details. What data do you have? Do you want to analyze something, or simply create something fancy? What have you researched so far?

Comment: At first glance, the following geoinstruments will suit you: 1) Multi Rings Buffer; 2) Create wedge buffers; 3) Intersecting...

Comment: I want to measure of LST of each buffer zone from the city core to eight directions and each buffer zone will be 1 km.